# Poles of a meromorphic function on riemann sphere is finite

Tags: riemann-surfaces

By identity theorem,I want to prove that every meromorphic function $f$ on riemann sphere $\mathbb{P}^1$ has finitely many poles, can this solution be true? :
Suppose $f$ has infinite poles then the restriction $f_{|\mathbb{P}^1\backslash\text{poles}}$ of $f$ is holomorphic and this set has limit point in $\mathbb{P}^1$ and since $f$ is continuous, $\lim f=f$ on this restricted set. Because this limit is infinite we conclude that $f$ is infinite every where and it's a contradiction.

Comment: poles are isolated singularities, so they must form a discrete (and thus finite, as the sphere is compact) subset

Comment: That's right,but I want to know the proof by identity theorem because in forster's book conclude this by identity theorem but didn't explain how.@user8268

Comment: then look at the zeroes of $1/f$ (which is basically what you wrote)

Comment: @user8268.so, is this a correct solution?